# What properties of a likelihood function are required for quasi-likelihood estimation?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, quasi-likelihood

Quasi-likelihood seems like a great way to use Iteratively Weighted Least Squares to fit linear models with a very general class of likelihoods.

But what is that class? Obviously the distribution must have a finite mean and a variance that can be expressed as a function of that mean. Are there cases when such a "variance function" doesn't exist? What other restrictions must the likelihood satisfy for this method to be valid?

Comment: Not sure how much help this is, but placing the Quasi-likelihood method within the context of M-estimation might help elucidate some of the properties. For example, looking at the quasi-score $U(y; \mu) = \frac{y_i - \mu}{\phi V(\mu)}$ the estimating equation $\sum_i U(y_i; \mu) = 0$ is an M-estimator ($\mu$ tacitly depending on a linear predictor).

Comment: I'm not sure it helps either. But I'd never heard the term "M-estimator" before, and the Wikipedia page was enlightening. So thanks for that.

Comment: given that quasi-likelihood estimators are M-estimators, I don't see why one can't apply the same theory.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure it says anything about the existence of variance functions.

Comment: For count and continuous data can't you explicitly construct a family of distributions with free mean and variance parameters and conclude existence of a distribution with a chosen variance function that way? The issue is that the quasi-likelihood won't correspond to its likelihood in general.

Comment: Sure, and my impression is that was the original idea behind quasi-likelihood. But I'm wondering about going the other way. Given some arbitrary likelihood $p$, can I use it to construct valid a quasi-likelihood estimating equation?